# Expected unqualified-id error in c++ for loop

Tags: c++

Please help this error has been driving me crazy and I have no idea how to fix it. The error occurs on the line indicated by the asterisks. In addition, throughout the entirety of that for loop it gives syntax errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(int rownum, int columnnum, bool israndom)
{
    this->rownum= rownum;
    this->columnnum= columnnum;

}

// Makes random number from 0-1
double Matrix::generaterand()
{
    double r= rand()/RAND_MAX;
    return r;
}

****** for(int i=0; i<rownum; i++) ********
{
    vector<double> columnvalues;

    for(int j=0; j<columnnum; j++)
    {
        double r = 0.00;

        if(isRandom)
        {
            r= generaterand();
        }

        columnvalues.push_back(r);
    }

    this->values.push_back(columnvalues);
}

void Matrix::printtoconsole()
{
    for(int i=0; i<rownum; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<columnnum; j++)
        {
        cout << this->values.at(i).at(j) << "\t\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a for loop outside of a function

Comment: You cannot place a `for` loop outside of any function body. Did you miss to establish a `main()` function there?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I am a baboon.

Comment: Could be worse. You could be a monkey. They can't code; they just write Shakespeare.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is not embedded in a function. It's just sitting alone while everything else you have is in its own functions. You should put it in its own function. That might help.